# Android AOSP SIOCADDRT ioctl call fail: Network is unreachable

Tags: android, embedded, android-source, ioctl

AOSP: Android Pie (android-9.0.0_r16)

Build: PQ1A.181105.017.A1

Device: Pixel 2

I am trying to connect cellular modem using dhcptool (renamed as dhcpdbg) with Android 9 Pie in RNDIS mode. The same setup worked fine for Previous versions of android but for Pie it fails on ioctl(3, SIOCADDRT, 0x7ffb9b8030). It says "Network is Unreachable".

I have checked the port i.e usb0 in ifconfig, it enumerates correctly but the dhcpdbg call fails and the network is not pingable.

Sepolicy on device is in permissive mode. Moreover, there are no permission or other errors in dmesg log.
Note: By default RNDIS drivers are not configured in Android Pie kernel so we enabled RNDIS mode in kernel and integrated changed kernel in AOSP source.

Here are some logs from "strace dhcpdbg usb0"

```
ioctl(3, SIOCGIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="usb0", ifr_flags=IFF_UP|IFF_BROADCAST|IFF_RUNNING|IFF_MULTICAST}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCSIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="usb0", ifr_flags=IFF_UP|IFF_BROADCAST|IFF_RUNNING|IFF_MULTICAST}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCSIFADDR, {ifr_name="usb0", ifr_addr={sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(0), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.1.100")}}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCSIFNETMASK, {ifr_name="usb0", ifr_netmask={sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(0), sin_addr=inet_addr("255.255.255.0")}}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCADDRT, 0x7ffb9b8030)       = -1 ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
close(3)                                = 0
getuid()                                = 0
writev(5, [{iov_base="\0\355\25o\6X\\=\267\254%", iov_len=11}, {iov_base="\3", iov_len=1}, {iov_base="DHCP\0", iov_len=5}, {iov_base="failed to set default         route 192."..., iov_len=65}], 4) = 82
getuid()                                = 0
writev(6, [{iov_base="lY\0\0\0\355\25", iov_len=7}, {iov_base="\0\355\25o\6X\\=\267\254%", iov_len=11}, {iov_base="\3", iov_len=1}, {iov_base="DHCP\0",     iov_len=5}, {iov_base="failed to set default route 192ioctl(3, SIOCADDRT, 0x7ffb9b8030)."..., iov_len=65}], 5) = 89
write(2, "dhcpdbg: ", 9dhcpdbg: )                = 9
write(2, "dhcptool usb0: do_dhcp failed", 29dhcptool usb0: do_dhcp failed) = 29
write(2, ": ", 2: )                       = 2
write(2, "Network is unreachable\n", 23Network is unreachable
) = 23
mprotect(0x6ffbc65000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
mprotect(0x6ffbc65000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x6ffbc65000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
mprotect(0x6ffbc65000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x6ffbc65000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
mprotect(0x6ffbc65000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x6ffbc65000, 4096)              = 0
exit_group(101)                         = ?
+++ exited with 101 +++
```

Below are some output of the networking commands:

ifconfig:

```
usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:06:06:15:00:0b  Driver rndis_host
      inet addr:192.168.1.100  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0 
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
      TX packets:80 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:1312 TX bytes:25155
```

ip add show:

```
28: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:06:06:15:00:0b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.100/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global usb0
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ip route show:

```
192.168.1.0/24 dev usb0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.100 
192.168.43.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.43.222
```

Kernel IP routing table:

```
Destination Gateway     Genmask     Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 usb0
192.168.43.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan0
```

ping 8.8.8.8:

```
connect: Network is unreachable
```

This dhcptool tool is working fine on all earlier android versions till Android 8.
Below is the working strace log from Android 8 dhcptool running on same usb0 port.

```
ioctl(3, SIOCGIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="usb0", ifr_flags=IFF_UP|IFF_BROADCAST|IFF_RUNNING|IFF_MULTICAST}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCSIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="usb0", ifr_flags=IFF_UP|IFF_BROADCAST|IFF_RUNNING|IFF_MULTICAST}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCSIFADDR, {ifr_name="usb0", ifr_addr={sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(0), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.1.100")}}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCSIFNETMASK, {ifr_name="usb0", ifr_netmask={sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(0), sin_addr=inet_addr("255.255.255.0")}}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCADDRT, 0x7fd2bb6cd0)       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/dev/socket/property_service"}, 31) = 0
writev(3, [{iov_base="\1\0\2\0", iov_len=4}, {iov_base="\r\0\0\0", iov_len=4}, {iov_base="net.usb0.dns1", iov_len=13}, {iov_base="\v\0\0\0", iov_len=4}, {iov_base="192.168.1.1", iov_len=11}], 5) = 36
recvfrom(3, "\0\0\0\0", 4, MSG_WAITALL, NULL, NULL) = 4
close(3)                                = 0
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/dev/socket/property_service"}, 31) = 0
writev(3, [{iov_base="\1\0\2\0", iov_len=4}, {iov_base="\r\0\0\0", iov_len=4}, {iov_base="net.usb0.dns2", iov_len=13}, {iov_base="\0\0\0\0", iov_len=4}], 4) = 25
recvfrom(3, "\0\0\0\0", 4, MSG_WAITALL, NULL, NULL) = 4
close(3)                                = 0
write(2, "dhcptool: ", 10dhcptool: )              = 10
write(2, "IP assignment is for debug purpo"..., 40IP assignment is for debug purposes ONLY) = 40
write(2, ": ", 2: )                       = 2
write(2, "Success\n", 8Success
)                = 8
mprotect(0x7729153000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
mprotect(0x7729153000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7729153000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
mprotect(0x7729153000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7729153000, 4096)              = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
bullhead:/ # ping 8.8.8.8                                                                                                                                                                                   
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=114 time=131 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=114 time=58.4 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 58.496/95.044/131.592/36.548 ms
bullhead:/ #
```

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the exact same situation, did you manage to find a solution for this? if so would you mind sharing?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're missing a route to 8.8.8.8 (probably the default route). Compare the routes between working and non-working set up.

Answer (score 0):

From the information shared above it appears that the default route is missing. You may add the default route using the command below:

```
ip route add default dev usb0
```

After adding the route above, I would recommend that you use the **traceroute** tool or **ping** (with TTL modified if traceroute isn't available) to trace the packets further from there.

Answer (score 0):

See https://elinux.org/Android_Networking#Setting_up_networking_on_bootup. The commands

```
netcfg eth0 dhcp
setprop net.dns1 8.8.8.8
```

should suffice.